# Multiple threads receive text from same socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am developing a code of a gateway device that receives data from a server on a single socket. This socket is being simultaneously read by multiple threads. However, multiple threads are not able to read the data. The system works perfectly when a single thread is reading the socket. Please let me know how can we allow multiple threads to read the same socket. Please find below the code snippet. I am using Java.

```
public void communication(Socket Server_sock, Socket dev_sock, String Dev_ID){
        BufferedReader br2;
        BufferedWriter bw2;

/*      try {
            br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Server_sock.getInputStream()));
            bw1=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Server_sock.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        String temp = null;
        while(true){
            try {
                temp  = br1.readLine();
                System.out.println(temp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(temp.startsWith("/devid/")){
                temp = temp.replace("/devid/", "");
                System.out.println(temp);
                System.out.println(Dev_ID);
                if(temp.equals(Dev_ID)){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Dev_auth");
                        bw1.write("1");
                        bw1.newLine();
                        bw1.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //if you want to have different functions for different type...create a check here and accordingly creaate new functions
                    dev_control(Server_sock, dev_sock);
                    continue;
                }
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }

    }

//Thread calling the aforementioned function

if(result.equals("1")){
                        System.out.println("Authenticated");
                        BufferedWriter bw;
//                      try {
                            String data = "/notif/"+temp[0]+":"+temp[2];
                            DataComm dc = new DataComm();
                            String test = dc.send_data(data);
/*                          bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Socket_server.getOutputStream()));
                            bw.write(data);
                            bw.newLine();
                            bw.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/
                        Online on = new Online(Arduino_IP_address,ad_sock, temp[0]);
                        Thread online = new Thread(on);
                        online.start();

                        dc.add_var(temp[0], ad_sock);
                        dc.communication(Socket_server,ad_sock,temp[0]);
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: You haven't indicated what language you're using. Please tag the question appropriately. Also, you havent specifies how your threads should cooperate to ensure they each get the right data. What is the data? How is it delimited? Why do you want to use multiple threads? As it is, this question can't be answered.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and still exploring all the option. Sorry for the miscommunication. I am using Java. Multiple device connect to the gateway and i require each device to have separate threads. further each thread is using same socket to communicate with the server. hope this answers your query.

Comment: Remove commented code and explain `multiple threads are not able to read the data.` **in details**. Is other thread stalls on a socket? Does error occure? Is incorrect data obtained?

Comment: Can you say what your desired behavior is?  Do the different threads send queries over the socket, and does each thread need to get the response to its own query, for example?

Comment: From your snippet is not clear what you have tried and why it has failed.

Comment: Just a note: if several thread reads same source atsame time, which of them you would like to receive the data, and how would do you think you could specify it?

Comment: i am trying to develop an IOT platform. I have a gateway that is connected to the server on a single socket. Multiple device connect to the gateway and  each device has individual threads created in the gateway. I want that each of these threads listen to the server socket and accordingly each thread receive the same data as transmitted by the server